# D3 map - filter on specific properties

Tags: d3.js

I am building a map with D3 that has text labels of country names. My problem is that I am generating too many country labels, and would like to manually select the countries to show.

What is the best way to do this? I can find my country names using

```
d.properties.name
```

Perhaps I could use d3.filter() but I don't know how I would write it

```
svg.selectAll(".place-label")
.data(topojson.feature(germany, germany.objects.populated).features)
.enter().append("text")
.attr("class", "place-label")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" +  projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; })
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });
```

Comment: Do you want the labels to be filtered so that specific labels will not be shown on the map?

Comment: That would be useful to know, but to filter based on several country names will work for me this time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter function like this:

```
.text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; })
.filter(function(labels) {
                    if(labels.properties.name == "some country name"){
                        //do stuff here
                    }
                    //or return the specific label and continue styling it afterwards
                    return labels.properties.name == "germany";
                })
.style("opacity",0);// make it dissappear
```

You can also place this inside an event like click.

Comment: I've tried this option and it works but for some odd reason the fitSize (using the same filtered data) makes the map disappear. In my non-js head it makes sense, use the filtered data to re fit the map using fitSize. Why?